# Asking about one post

Tags: discussion, support, questions

I have a question about my Islam Stack Exchange post: [Looking to communicate with Allah and getting supplications as well as prayers accepted](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/73898/looking-to-communicate-with-allah-and-getting-supplications-as-well-as-prayers-a)

I wanted this post to benefit the community as well as myself. I wanted to ask this question in a way journalist or newsreporter ask question from an authority figure.
I want this post to be educational community run and moderated properly.One post collects all the answers to this question and everyone gets to respond . The best answers are voted up and I can choose the answer im looking for.
This question will help everyone . Please allow it and reconsider voting or ask this question yourself , any moderator can ask it.
I don't want negative effects of this question.  It does not have clear answer so let's gather all possible answers.

Answer (score 2):

The title of the posting you are asking about isn't a question, and the body of the question itself doesn't contain a single "?".
There is no actual question in the posting.

*Questions must be in the form of a question.*

It does however contain 2 "me"s, 2 "my"s, and 12 "I"s.

*Questions must be about something that could be of concern to others, not about you.*

Please take the time to think about what fundamental question you really want answered, and then ask that question, as clearly as possible, and omitting all references to yourself.

*Well thought out, well presented, reasonable questions* do *get answers.*